# how to start a android service from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am trying to write an nativescript application for android... i have a javascript file from where i need to call a intent to start a service. The code which i want to invoke in my javascript file is in https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.ts from line 35 to 47. 
Also i have to port the entire piece of source of code present in https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/background-service.ts to javascript file. 
i am not sure how to port code " @JavaProxy("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService")" to javascript.

Regards,
Akarsh

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript translation of `@JavaProxy("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService")` would be,

```
    var BackgroundService = android.app.Service.extend("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService", {
        ...
    });
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages) more info.

Comment: It's a common issue while coding proxy classes, try a clean build you should be good.

Comment: var BackgroundServiceClass = android.app.Service.extend("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService",{
 Exception in thread "main" 
java.io.IOException: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.
Please change the name of one of the extended classes. java/com/nativescript/location/BackgroundService.java Class: com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService
at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:112)
 at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:53)

Comment: Did you try a clean build? Tried deleting platforms folder?